# How can I put icons inside image, move the icons only inside the image using my mouse and save their locations inside the image?

Tags: image, svg, image-processing, icons, medical

for a project, I am trying to provide a user interface where a user can position sensors on a foot and then save the sensors position in the image to display them later :  [image: Foot mapping with sensors location]
In doing, so I create 5 images, one per sensor and the image of the foot mapping but I have no idea how to put the sensors icon in the image and then save their position inside the image. I have the following code :

```html
<p>Put on the foot mapping the sensors position</p>
                      <img
                          alt="foot_mapping"
                          src={require("assets/img/theme/circle-1.png")}
                          class="inner-image"
                          width="40em"
                          height="40em"
                          />
                           <img
                          alt="foot_mapping"
                          src={require("assets/img/theme/circle-2.png")}
                          class="inner-image"
                          width="40em"
                          height="40em"
                          />
                           <img
                          alt="foot_mapping"
                          src={require("assets/img/theme/circle-3.png")}
                          class="inner-image"
                          width="40em"
                          height="40em"
                          />
                           <img
                          alt="foot_mapping"
                          src={require("assets/img/theme/circle-4.png")}
                          class="inner-image"
                          width="40em"
                          height="40em"
                          />
                           <img
                          alt="foot_mapping"
                          src={require("assets/img/theme/circle-5.png")}
                          class="inner-image"
                          width="40em"
                          height="40em"
                          />
                      <img
                          alt="foot_mapping"
                          src={require("assets/img/theme/foot.png")}
                          width="80%"
                          height="80%"
                        />
```

I tried the inner image with no luck yet and I didn't find other ressources regarding this problem.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You may try to give the sensors a position absolute and place both the foot and the sensors in the same `position:relative` parent. Next you can give the sensors a `top` and `left`.  I see you are using the svg tag. Why?

Comment: @enxaneta Good idea ! I used the svg tag because I thought about displaying the sensors as svg but it wasn't a good idea. Thanks I will try it :)